# My Flutter app is not generating .g.dart files

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit2, pubspec.yaml

I am trying to generate g.dart file in app using "flutter pub run build_runner build" but no fill is created why i have no idea even file name is same also check dependences also.

[this is the file which is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm5wc.png)

[this is my api_services class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txIHe.png)

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: pls share your pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've installed [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) package, if you haven't run the following command to install it to your dev dependencies:

```bash
dart pub add dev:build_runner
```

Now, run the following command to build `.g.dart` files. The following command runs for a single time and generates the builds.

```bash
dart run build_runner build
```

If anything goes wrong, please share more details.